# Vampires getting away with ritual murder

Tags: vampires

I have a special breed of vampires. They are, like any vampire, dependent of human blood and they need to consume it every few days in order to stay active. If they don't, they go into coma, and eventually die. They are weaker than people of the same size and they don't have any special power, except for their heightened senses (sight, smell, hearing). They mostly like to act at night, as the sun light affects them.

The question is how would they get their blood without raising suspicion? They could start a blood bank, and some blood could magically disappear. They could also start a morgue, or a funeral home and use the blood from the bodies of deceased people.

But, they also have rituals for bringing back some older deceased vampires and they need fresh warm blood. How could they setup a police-proof scheme for kidnapping people and sacrificing them in their rituals?

Comment: It looks like you're asking about a plan made by a specific group of individuals to take actions against a group of individuals while concealing their actions from another group of individuals in your already built world. Such story based questions are not a good fit for this site.

Comment: "_they don't have any special powers_" doesn't quite gel with "_they also have rituals for bringing back some older deceased vampires_".

Comment: Anyway, I think I'm with sphennings on this one, so VTC. Have you considered just having your vamps _buy_ the blood, though?

Answer (score 4):

### They are the police

Infiltration would likely be required to establish a lasting source, being able to cover tracks is one thing, but to be able to prevent action due to the uncovering of those tracks would be even better.

They perfer the night, and police will often have shifts as they need to be available should something happen over night. This is where they can perform in plain sight, using their enhanced senses to better detect potential victims.

From a single feeding from a "hostile assailant" that had to be shot in self defense (or bled dry and then shot after) to entire divisions rounding up the homeless into a blood farm with cooperation potentially from other vampires that have infiltrated the state government.

Law doesn't enforce itself, so if you can control the enforcement of law, you can get around that enforcement. If someone reports it, internal investigations find no wrong doing, and even if it was found, state persecution may put forward such a bad case (intentionally) to let the bad cop walk.

Comment: Bled before being shot will be detected at autopsy.

Comment: But who's performing the autopsy, or even ordering such?

Comment: You either need an autopsy or a doctor signing off on it being natural causes.  Bullet-riddled certainly isn't natural causes, there's going to be an autopsy.

Comment: I'm saying you could bribe or plant the doctor or whoever needs to sign the paper.

Comment: And you can control it?  What happens when some family member doesn't believe what happened and hires another doctor to do an autopsy?

Comment: @LorenPechtel The Author can. Really depends on how far the infiltration goes in the story. We have many irl examples of government processes being built in ways to only slightly serve the public while really supporting those who built the system in ways that aren't plainly easy to root out. Tax loopholes, Money havens, Police investigating themselves to find "no wrongdoing" (Cop killed an innocent? Intentionally or not, Q.I. must be forced to care.) Corruption is nothing new. That being said, your example may be a plot point which sparks an investigation which uncovers these situations

Comment: I got the impression it was how to hide it in our world.

Answer (score 1):

### They won't need to hide their habits

A few options to explain, if you would choose that line of story,

**Privileges, vampires are elite**

One option commonly chosen in vampire stories. The victim will be the beautiful farmer's daughter, seduced by a handsome wealthy vampire and introduced in high society circles, where all folks are actually vampires. She'll be bit, become a vampire and join the party. This approach is taken in the well known TV series "The Originals".

**They move in a blink**

Another option commonly used. Vampires just appear suddenly, abduct their victim and disappear. No one knows where they reside and everybody is VERY afraid of them. They won't be held accountable for anything, if you're lucky you have a brave hero roaming around killing vampires with wooden sticks.

**Everyone wants to be a vampire**

In your e.g. cyberpunk or steampunk world, people won't mind murder, or a little blood loss. They know once they are bit by a vampire, they will become vampires and immortal. Folks would want to be immortal.. and in this culture, it is considered a challenge to find a vampire and seduce it.

**Vampires are executioners**

Inspired by Danger Lake's answer, without the secrecy. Vampires are employed by the government, to officially perform the death penalty, by decapitating criminals. They can do whatever they like with their victims, no one is interested. When the victim is especially beautiful, the vampire will not kill the convicted person, rather turn it into a vampire and marry it.

**Accepted habits**

Vampires are citizens with certain habits accepted in society. They can buy human blood, and when they don't feel well and need fresh blood, they go to the doctor, who can provide them with it.